# Python Variable Scope in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I am having some trouble enabling or finding a way to **enable python variable scope in Sublime Text 3**.
I have found two excellent plugins which do the following:

- [Colorcoder](https://github.com/vprimachenko/Sublime-Colorcoder) which adds custom colors to unique identifiers in code.
- [Python Improved](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved) which adds more Python language definitions for Sublime Text.

However Python Improved does not add support for variables.

[image]

As you can see from the picture above when using the Monokai theme. When I look at the current scope of a specific variable it simply states that its source.python. Is there any syntax definition out there which can correctly recognize python variables in scope in Sublime Text 3?

Comment: I'm the author of Python Improved. What do you mean by a "variable"? I (and the authors of the default `Python.sublime-syntax` that ships with Sublime) have chosen not to highlight every single identifier, as it would be meaningless, essentially.

Comment: Above `statement` is a variable [name of an object]. I wish for a specific scope for variables. Variables above would be `(sources)` `Sources.(id)` `Sources.(data)` `(data_date)` `Performances.(fund_id)` `(fund_id)` etc. Thank you

Comment: OK, I see. Can you do me a favor and open an issue in the Python Improved repo regarding this? Please include some example code as text (so I can copy and paste), the longer the better, and specify exactly what should be highlighted and what shouldn't be (this is definitely important - I need negative cases as well). I'll look for patterns and see if I can come up with some regexes that would suffice.